# JAXB unmarshalling non wrapped elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have following input coming in to my app from 3rd party

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <document>
      <name>Foobar</name>
      <descriprion>Foobar Foobar</descriprion>
      <lead>Lorem</lead>
      <bodytext>Foobar Foobar Lorem</bodytext>

      <ImageFile1>pic123</ImageFile1>
      <caption1><![CDATA[yadda yadda]]></caption1>
      <photographer1><![CDATA[Mr. Foobar]]></photographer1>
      <crop1>1.01 0 0 1.01 0 -80000 0</crop1>
      <width1>283.86</width1>
      <height1>164.51</height1>

      ...

      <ImageFile38>000bemdt</ImageFile38>
      <caption38><![CDATA[Ljubov Kavaljova]]></caption38>
      <photographer38><![CDATA[]]></photographer38>
      <crop38>1.24 0 0 1.24 -369326 -69264 0</crop38>
      <width38>44.10</width38>
      <height38>68.35</height38>
    </document>
```

I'm unmarshalling the XML into an object X. Notice that the image file elements are not wrapped but numbered! How can I unmarshall those non wrapped  and the related elements into a List of objects, which I set into the List type field of the object X?

```
public class Article()
{
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String lead;
  private String bodytext;
  private List<Picture> pictures;
}

public class Picture()
{
  private String fileName;
  private String caption;
  private String photographer;
  private String crop;
  private String width;
  private String height;
}
```

Comment: JAXB cannot be used in this case, as mapping from Java to XML becomes non-deterministic (`pictures.get(0).getCaption()` should be mapped to `<caption1>`, but `pictures.get(1)`... – not). Only your application can control this mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XmlAnyElement` annotation.

Look at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html).